# Activity Dialog

Tags: android

I am coding a simple game, with two image buttons: "options" and "shop".

I want it so that when clicking on an image button it produces a window where I can do something, and then go back to main activity. I want it also so that this newly opened window will not be full-screen, so I can see main activity darkened under the opened window.

What method is best to use?
Is "activity" good, or are there any better alternatives?

Also, how can I access variables from main activity to use in opened activity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, how can I access variables from main activity to use in opened activity? I have a button on second activity and by onClick  I want to increase variable in main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to do 'something' on the screen that you want as a pop-up over your main activity, I would suggest you to use the second activity as pop-up.

you can achieve this by setting the second activity's theme to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in the manifest.

This will make your second activity appear like a dialog, floating on top of main activity.

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Hi, Biju.
Thank you. I've tried make this, but when second activity tries to open - my app is crashing.

Comment: Could you please post the StackTrace?

Comment: Biju,
I have maked a mistake. My primary activity was extends AppCompatActivity, not Activity. Now it works fine.
But I have also a question - how can I change variables from Main Activity in a Dialog Activity? I've tried to extends main activity, and accessed variables, but as I understood - variable scope in dialog activity is local.

Comment: You Welcome :)
The other case you can post it as an another question, it's difficult to post code in comments, you know ;)

Comment: Yep. Thanks. I will try to find a solution without make too much stupid questions :-)

Comment: you can revise the solution I gave you as it generate a new activity that have much more flexibility there.

Answer (score 1):

well you would want to use an Activity ofcourse to control what will appear and happen on this and you would also need to create a proper .xml file for it with specific definitions for it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByusCMz9WiFQUFpzZm91T1VnY2M/view

at this project by Filip Vujuvic you have a very good project code implementing floating window using a new Activity and a new XML.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting to use standard android widgets, this sounds like a dialog type of screen; you could use....

A Dialog/[DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) or a [Popup Window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html).

A popup window might be a little more complicated to write but can give you more flexibility.

A DialogFragment is probably easier to write and gives you the floating/dimming effect by default.

If I were you, I'd start with a DialogFragment and see how it works for you.

Hope this helps.